# if $p:\widetilde{X}\rightarrow X$ is a covering space and $\widetilde{X}$ is path connected ,show that $p^{-1}(A)$ is path connected.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

if $p:\widetilde{X}\rightarrow X$ is a covering space and $\widetilde{X}$ is path connected ,also $A\subset X$ is a path connected subset,show that $p^{-1}(A)$ is path connected.

I suppose that $p^{-1}(A)$ isn't path connected and I think it will come something contradiction  to the covering space but I don't know how should I continue.please help me with your knowledge,thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Take any connected covering of degree $d>1$ and $A$ a point. $p^{-1}(A)$ has $d$ connected components, while $A$ is connected.

Comment: I am little confused can you explain what is the connected covering of degree d,and also you mean that my way is wrong?

Comment: "any" means choose any. choose your preferred covering $p:\tilde X\to X$ such that $\tilde X$ is connected. if $\tilde X$ is different to $X$ then any point has at least two preimages.

Comment: so you mean that the question is wrong,it won't be path connected.do you have any Idea what condition make it right?

Comment: yes, the question has a negative answer: it is not true that for any connected $A$, its inverse image is connected. What do you mean for "make the question right"?

Comment: I wanted to prove that the inverse image is always path connected,now I know that it is not always true,so I mean that when it always path connected?

Comment: basically never, a part for specific cases

Comment: for example if $\pi_*:\pi_1(A)\to\pi_1(X)$ is onto, then $p^{-1}(A)$ is connected

Comment: I can't imagine in this special case what happened to $p^{-1}(A)$?can you explain a little more?

Comment: I think you're right,thank you for your comment,I must think more about it.

Comment: Dear kpax, I have deleted my comment since you seem to agree with its advice.

Comment: @user126154 : Please help me with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240844/simply-connected-covering-of-a-path-connected-space

Answer (score 1):

Massey's book on "Algebraic Topology" gave some information on the connectivity of a pullback of a covering map; a more complete account is given in this paper ["Groupoids and the Mayer-Vietoris sequence"](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/bhk-gpds-mv.pdf) JPAA 30 (1983) 109-129. It uses the notion of **covering morphism of groupoids**, which encapsulates the notion of covering map of spaces.  So from a pullback of a covering morphism you get a covering morphism, and by choosing base points you get a  diagram involving various vertex groups and sets of components the exactness properties of which enables you to read of facts about connectivity etc. This result is also in [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html), Section 10.7, but is a bit too long to give here.

Comment: thank you very much professor brown.

Comment: Dear Ronnie, I don't see how the results you quote are relevant to the question. The restriction to $A$ of a covering is a covering and the corresponding covering space is not connected (except in trivial cases) if $A$ is sufficiently small. How on earth will  someone who doesn't understand such a triviality  be helped by trying to read  complicated results on groupoids involving non-abelian cohomology ?

Comment: @ George: I have been trying since the publication of the first edition of my topology book in 1968 to persuade people that groupoids are not complicated, but are a more natural way than just using groups to express intuitive ideas on 1-dimensional homotopy theory, and to get more powerful theorems sometimes with simpler proofs.   My book does not use nonabelian cohomology. The MV sequence ties in the various vertex groups and sets of components involved in the pullback in a way I liked, so I mention it. If a reader does not like it, OK.

Comment: @George: It is useful to point out that restriction is a special case of pullback. In general, I don't think that beginners should be deprived of the fact that a more general point of view is possible, and let them decide. This type of comment may also be useful for more experienced readers, and writers.

Answer (score 0):

It is true in the trivial case of $d=1$, $p:X\rightarrow X$. We know that if $p:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ is a covering and $X$ is locally path-connected then so is $X$.

Comment: Such a tautology in no way constitutes an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to comment.

Comment: My recent paper  arXiv:2001.00534v2  examines the early 20th century search for higher dimensional generalisations   of the fundamental group,  which resulted in the initial lack of welcome of E. Cech's definition of abelian higher homotopy groups at the 1932 Zurich ICM, and the more recent aim of  applying groupoids (and so _many base points_), which does allow such (strict) non abelian generalisations, for certain structured spaces.